# Where to place immediately

Tags: adverbs

Which one of the following three sentences is correct

> It is time to **immediately** put the work in hand.

> It is time to put the work **immediately** in hand.

> It is time to put the work in hand **immediately**.

Answer (score 1):

The word is redundant, but this is fine because it will understood as adding emphasis.  I would choose the third, but I might put a comma before *immediately*.

Immediately means that there is no intermediate thing - nothing between this and that.  The second sentence means a different thing that the first and the third - it means that there is nothing between the hand and the work.  It has a sense of being a spacial relationship, rather than simply a temporal one - or perhaps I should say a sequential/ordinal relationship - the work is to be done before other work.  Some native speakers will miss this nuance.